# Sources of Elementary Number Theory Problems

Tags: elementary-number-theory, reference-request, soft-question, big-list

I am looking for sources of interesting and challenging problems that would suitably accompany an honors level introductory number theory course.

**What are some good sources for *interesting* elementary number theory problems?**

Edit: I am specifically looking for problems that would nicely complement a book such as Ivan Niven's *[Introduction to the Theory of Numbers](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0471625469)* that are not standard exercises, but rather interesting and challenging gems.

Comment: Downvoting this question is, at least, surprising...Anyway, you can try googling "number theory exercised" or so, @Antoine

Comment: @DonAntonio This I have done, but I am really looking for sources of particularly interesting gems -- not just standard exercises.

Comment: would it be a bad idea to look at the arXiv:[ http://front.math.ucdavis.edu/math.NT ]?

Comment: another sample [ http://mathoverflow.net/questions/59192/is-oeis-a001935-number-of-partitions-with-no-even-part-repeated-efficiently-co ] which mention the **OEIS**.

Comment: or an entire collection: [ http://mathoverflow.net/search?q=number+theory ]

Comment: @janmarqz: Will the arXiv really have collections of *elementary* number theory problems? Maybe you'd have more luck with MO, but I can't imagine by much.

Comment: Maybe this should be made a community wiki?

Comment: @rghthndsd: you can dig it... and anyone

Answer (score 6):

I totally recommend [250 problems of elementary number theory](http://it.scribd.com/doc/26892740/250-Problems-in-Elementary-Number-Theory)

Answer (score 3):

The following seems to fit the bill, though I must admit to only taking a glance through.

http://www.math.muni.cz/~bulik/vyuka/pen-20070711.pdf

Comment: When I read the question, I immediately wanted to mention the PEN-list. Too late...